# Use List.js with table and a filter box for each column

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to use List.js for a filter option for a table. I am able to get it to filter over one column with one search box, but what I want to do is have a filter box for each column.
This is the HTML for the table:

```
<div id="myTable">
    <h1>My Table</h1>
    <div>
        <input class="search" placeholder="Filter ID" />
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="cols" class="sortable" >ID</th>
                <th id="cols" class="sortable" >First Name</th>
                <th id="cols" class="sortable" >Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="list">
            <tr class="even">
                <td id="cols" class="id">12345</td>
                <td id="cols" class="firstName">Billy</td> 
                <td id="cols" class="lastName">Joe</td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript code:

```
var options = {
     valueNames: ['id']
};
var userList = new List('myTable', options)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the [**List API**](http://listjs.com/docs/list-api/) `search` method to filter the columns by `id`.

```js
var searchInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var options = {
  valueNames: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName']
};
var userList = new List('myTable', options)

function search ( e ) {
  userList.search(this.value, e.target.dataset.searchType)
}

searchInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('input', search)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.3.0/list.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTable">
  <h1>My Table</h1>
  <div>
    <input data-search-type="id" class="search" placeholder="Search ID" />
    <input data-search-type="firstName" class="search" placeholder="Search First Name" />
    <input data-search-type="lastName" class="search" placeholder="Search Last Name" />
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="cols" class="sortable" >ID</th>
        <th id="cols" class="sortable" >First</th>
        <th id="cols" class="sortable" >Last</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr class="even">
        <td id="cols" class="id">1</td>
        <td id="cols" class="firstName">John</td> 
        <td id="cols" class="lastName">Doe</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td id="cols" class="id">2</td>
        <td id="cols" class="firstName">Jane</td> 
        <td id="cols" class="lastName">Doe</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td id="cols" class="id">3</td>
        <td id="cols" class="firstName">Foo</td> 
        <td id="cols" class="lastName">Bar</td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Another option would be to use the `filter` method.

```js
var searchInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var options = {
  valueNames: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName']
};
var userList = new List('myTable', options)

function search ( e ) {
  var curr = e.target;
  userList.filter(function(item) {
    if(item.values()[curr.dataset.searchType].indexOf(curr.value) > -1) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })
}

searchInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('input', search)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.3.0/list.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTable">
  <h1>My Table</h1>
  <div>
    <input data-search-type="id" class="search" placeholder="Search ID" />
    <input data-search-type="firstName" class="search" placeholder="Search First Name" />
    <input data-search-type="lastName" class="search" placeholder="Search Last Name" />
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="cols" class="sortable" >ID</th>
        <th id="cols" class="sortable" >First</th>
        <th id="cols" class="sortable" >Last</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr class="even">
        <td id="cols" class="id">1</td>
        <td id="cols" class="firstName">John</td> 
        <td id="cols" class="lastName">Doe</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td id="cols" class="id">2</td>
        <td id="cols" class="firstName">Jane</td> 
        <td id="cols" class="lastName">Doe</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td id="cols" class="id">3</td>
        <td id="cols" class="firstName">Foo</td> 
        <td id="cols" class="lastName">Bar</td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for. What I have right now along with including the List.js library already filters the list by ID. What I want to do is include two more boxes, one for first name and the other for last name, that way someone can filter by id and then filter further by first name and so on.

Comment: I clarified the question so it is clear that I want to filter the table.

Comment: The `filter` method seems to work a lot better. Thank you for your response.